# External Procedure memory allocations

Tags: oracle, plsql, external, procedure

I have some existing functions written in C that take pointers to two arrays and do some calculations on the data. I wanted to call those functions from PL/SQL as external procedures. Our data is stored in Oracle as a BLOB. So, I made a wrapper shared object to be called from PL/SQL. It felt like overkill to pass the BLOB into every wrapper function and parse it into these two arrays with every single external procedure call. So, instead I made a function called ParseBlobToArrays
which looks like:

```
int OracleBlobToDataArrays(OCIExtProcContext* ctx,OCILobLocator* blob,
                          //some other stuff I can't post used to parse blob, 
                          unsigned int* address1, unsigned int* address2) 
  {                
      //this isn't all the code, error checking etc here as well
      unsigned char* buf = OCIExtProcAllocCallMemory(ctx,lobLen ))

      //read blob into allocated buf 
      double* arr1 = ParseToArray1(buf,//some additional params);
      float** arr2 = ParseToArray2(buf,//some additional params); 
      *address1= (unsigned int)((uintptr_t) arr1);
      *address2= (unsigned int)((uintptr_t) arr2);
  }
```

I then return the addresses and feed them into each subsequent function that needs them and set them appropriately:

```
double OtherFunctionWrapper(unsigned int address1,unsigned int address2)
{
  double* arr1 = (double*)address1;
  float** arr2 = (float**)address2;

  return DoCalculation(arr1,arr2);;
}
```

I then call a Free wrapper function I wrote which takes the addresses, casts again to appropriate types and then frees all the pointers.

There is a code smell I don't like:
The C code is passing memory addresses like this when PL/SQL doesn't seem to support a uintptr_t/64 bit binary integer (or even exposing these raw addresses at all). Casting and returning the address as a UINT32 and then moving this to 64 bit OS in the future would potentially blow up I believe, if the address doesn't fit in a UINT32.

I could parse the data into arrays and return them to PL/SQL as OCIColls, but then I need to use OCI specific data types etc. This is safer (I think?), but I already have the BLOB parsed and in memory to be used. Seems silly to pass data back to PL/SQL as PL/SQL supported types just to be passed in to other functions, when all I really need is a pointer to data that already exists in the format I want in memory.

Any advice on handling this differently? If the right option is to do everything with supported PL/SQL datatypes and return them accordingly, I will. But I am looking for other options as well to minimize duplicate code with each call to various calculation functions since speed of these external procedures is very important.

Thanks!

Comment: I am curious what this code does, that is cannot be implemented in pl/sql or a java stored proc?

Comment: @OldProgrammer - presumably the key phrase is "some existing functions written in C".

Comment: Because we are doing complex number math. The test time of a device is around 200 milliseconds. In the future it might be much lower (sub 100 ms), and we are loading and doing data analysis on the fly. We had a complex class in PL/SQL and cranking all our calculations using the class was not giving us the performance we wanted. Our full load and calculation time was pushing up against test time. With C, the calculations are basically in the noise.